# Why is torque sometimes reported in kg m, instead of the usual N m?

Tags: mass, torque, units, dimensional-analysis, weight

On various websites I see torque expressed as $\rm kg\: m$, but I was always thought that torque is $\rm N\:m$ or $\rm kg\: m^2/s^2$. These are clearly not the same, so why are they called the same, and when do I use one or the other?

Comment: Don’t trust websites for introductory physics help. There’s a lot of crap and noise out there. The one you were always taught is perfectly right!

Comment: @knzhou I see this unit of torque _kg/m_ , in the details of electric motors. They always give the torque of an electric motor in _kg/m_. Do they just call it "torque" but mean something else?

Comment: @knzhou Actually "kg/m" was probably just a mistake on this website, they probably meant _kg*m_.

Comment: It has any number of units, since there are any number of unit systems. In cgs it has  unit $dyne \cdot cm$. If you stick to a single unit system you cannot go wrong. My advise is mksi, so $Nm$.

Comment: @sparpo, kg is a unit of mass, and N is a unit of force.  kg-m is NOT a unit of torque.  This usage no doubt comes from the usage of ft-lb in the English system, but what most people don't realize is that there are pounds-force and pounds-mass, and the two units differ by a factor of 32.2.

Comment: @DavidWhite I would have expected the two kinds of pound to differ by something with dimension of acceleration, not by a scalar??

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, the factor is 32.2 ft/s^2, which is, as expected, 9.8 m/s^2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those other sources were probably referring to kilogram-force instead of Newtons. Given the constant conversion between mass and weight on Earth (i.e., $g = 9.8\,\textrm{m/s}^2$), mass and weight units are often used interchangeably in non-scientific contexts. So, torque can be expressed in kgf-m, where 1 kgf is the weight of 1 kg on Earth's surface. Notice that this is a multiplication, not a division. Units of kgf/m would be completely incorrect.

Comment: Yes, and in particular it is strictly speaking _wrong_ - though commonly done, and moreover this shows exactly why you _shouldn't do it_ - to write the unit kgf as "kg".

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Nah, it's fine in the right context. As long as your audience understands, anything works. Though I do get more annoyed at particle physicists who set $c=1$. The equation $E^2 = m^2 + p^2$ makes me twitch due to the loss of units.

Comment: The problem is there are then _two_ units with the _same_ symbol and yet quite different meanings, and they are likely to be in rather close proximity with each other if not coming together. That's a recipe for confusion. Moreover when I say "wrong" I mean with regard to the standards that define the meaning of the symbol $\mathrm{kg}$. That's why I said "strictly speaking", i.e. according to rigorous application of the standards.

Comment: And yes, you don't _have_ to follow standards, but if your usages are not strongly set apart enough, you are creating a recipe for confusion with more standard usages. Especially if your non-standard usages blur together lines that should otherwise be there - e.g. force _is not_ mass.

Comment: And with something like torque where mass enters in in a significant way, there is strong potential for contact between the two and that (depending on what kind of measurements you're given) may lead to improper unit arithmetic which is a mistake and _definitely_ wrong by the rules of mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

The non SI unit is often written as 1 kg-m and is equal to 9.8 N m.

In such a case the 1 kg refers to the unit 1 [kg force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram-force) which is the weight of one kilogram.

Another unit is the Imperial (and US) unit the pound-foot which is equal to approximately 1.36 N m.
Here the unit of force is the [pound force.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force))

Answer (score 1):

Well I think both of the Units are right. But its not kgm it should be kgf-m.
Torque means - - - >   F×R. ..
 Hence it has units of Force times distance.

N-m is one of the units where N is unit of Force and m is distance.. While in 
Kgf-m Kgf is unit of force and m is distance as Usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think we don’t need to use gravity in all of our equations. It’s only a theory and with no use. Variables like forces and pressure and others are based on “g”, that’s why you can’t exclude it. It’s sometimes hidden in the constants where it is not shown in equations. Those constants were found based on experiments and calculations where g was included, e.g. spring constant. If we rewrite our physics without gravity, I believe it should be working well. When you give units like N, J or Watt, it gives no physical meaning but just a respect for those people. We live in different era, and we should be more serious about physics rather than turning it to a history class.